# self.title vs self.navigationItem.title

Tags: iphone

What is the purpose of the `title` property of UIViewController, can't the title already be set with `navigationItem.title` ?

Both seem to work, I'm just wondering why there's this seemingly duplicated functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The title of a view controller is both a convention and a convenience for you as a programmer.  Calling...

```
self.title = @"Some Title";
```

or

```
[self setTitle:@"Some Title"];
```

ensures that any object (like the navigation bar) that needs to retrieve the title of your view controller can do so.  Using navigationItem.title will allow you to over-ride this title as needed but it may be consider more "stylish" to set the title of your controller instead.

IMO you can do either but the former will save you some typing ;-)

Cheers-

Answer (score 34):

In a UIViewController, title and navigationItem.title are different. One example: if you have a view controller (in a NavigationController) in a UITabBarController, then if you set self.title it overrides the name of the tab as well as the top title. If you set self.navigationItem.title then it only changes the top title, leaving the tab bar name unchanged.

Answer (score 7):

When you set `navigationItem.title` you are setting the title of the navigation bar on the top of the view.  This is important when you push a new view controller because the title of the previous view (as set by `navigationItem.title`) will be the text of the back button.  Further, if your project does not have a navigation bar, `navigationItem.title` will not work.

Apple gives the following description for the `title` property of UIViewController.

> A localized string that represents the view that this controller manages.

Answer (score 4):

UIViewController has the title property. in navigationItem and tabBarItem both override the title property. so if we have application with tabbar and navigationcontroller.and setting self.title=@"somethng" will set that title to both navigationTitle and tabBartitle.